# Python argparse AssertionError when running —h

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparse in my python code, but when i run the following in command line

```
python samplecode.py —h
```

I get assertion error.

Here is the code in samplecode.py

```
import argparse

def getCommandLineData():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Extract candidate data from Talentforce Archive')
    parser.add_argument('--email', metavar='',required=True, help='Email of the candidate')
    parser.add_argument('--archiveDir', metavar='',required=False, help='Directory where Archived Data is kept')
    parser.add_argument('--chunksize',type=int , metavar='',required=False, help='Number of Rows CSV files will be broken into')
    parser.add_argument('--outputDir', metavar='',required=False, help='Output Directory for Extracted Data')
    parser.add_argument('--databasePath', metavar='',required=False, help='Full Path to database File')
    args = parser.parse_args()

getCommandLineData()
```

Error that i get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "samplecode.py", line 12, in <module>
    getCommandLineData()
  File "samplecode.py", line 10, in getCommandLineData
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1749, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1781, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1987, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1927, in consume_optional
    take_action(action, args, option_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1855, in take_action
    action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1037, in __call__
    parser.print_help()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 2474, in print_help
    self._print_message(self.format_help(), file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 2458, in format_help
    return formatter.format_help()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 284, in format_help
    help = self._root_section.format_help()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 215, in format_help
    item_help = join([func(*args) for func, args in self.items])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 215, in <listcomp>
    item_help = join([func(*args) for func, args in self.items])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 339, in _format_usage
    assert ' '.join(opt_parts) == opt_usage
AssertionError
```

I am out of ideas as to why i am getting the error. If i comment out few of the parser.add_argument lines, error goes away. But i am unable to establish a pattern or a root cause

Comment: The usage formatting is fragile, and breaks with unusual metavar values. Don't try anything fancy there. It's a known bug/issue that won't be fixed anytime soon.

Comment: Playing around with this, I see there's an interaction between the '' metavar, the `required` value, and the line length.  The `usage` line is long enough to split into two lines.  The error occurs when it tries to make sure nothing gets messed up in the split.  But the mix of brackets and metavar space is messing up that naive check.  We could go into more details on why it fails, but I think it's enough to say, use the '' metavar at your own risk.

Comment: Your metavars are not valid.

Comment: Thanks guys. Removing metavar helped. I am new to python, so just googled about argparse and wrote that code. I will study more into what metavar is and how to use it. But for now, all three of you got it right. I wish i could mark your comments as the accepted answer.